# export default use choice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies if my question sounds stupid but I ' m a noob  :-/
I found something strange in this  [github file](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/library/latest-posts/block.js).
I know we can export or import default function but here
the author use :

```
export default withAPIData( ( props ) => {
    const { postsToShow, order, orderBy, categories } = props.attributes;
    const queryString = stringify( pickBy( {
        categories,
        order,
        orderBy,
        per_page: postsToShow,
        _fields: [ 'date_gmt', 'link', 'title' ],
    }, value => ! isUndefined( value ) ) );
    return {
        latestPosts: `/wp/v2/posts?${ queryString }`,
    };
} )( LatestPostsBlock );
```

but he use what he gets with `latestPosts: /wp/v2/posts?${ queryString }` in the render() with

```
const latestPosts = this.props.latestPosts.data;
```

I don't understand why use export default if he want to use he result in the same file.

Comment: he using this in another file https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/library/latest-posts/index.js

Comment: The code you've posted is too fragmentary (and the question must be entirely self-contained). Please post a [mcve] demonstrating what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He does not export something named "withAPIData", he exports the result of that function as "default".

Here is an equivalent:

```
const ConnectedLatestPostsBlock = withAPIData( ( props ) => {
  const { postsToShow, order, orderBy, categories } = props.attributes;
  const queryString = stringify( pickBy( {
    categories,
    order,
    orderBy,
    per_page: postsToShow,
    _fields: [ 'date_gmt', 'link', 'title' ],
  }, value => ! isUndefined( value ) ) );
  return {
    latestPosts: `/wp/v2/posts?${ queryString }`,
  };
} )( LatestPostsBlock );

export default ConnectedLatestPostsBlock;
```

He passes his component (LastestPostsBlock) to the HOC [(High Order Component)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which clones the component at render time and passes more props down to it. In this case the prop "data".